# Are there any security vulnerabilities in this php code?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I would like to know if there are any security vulnerabilities in this code:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Dashboard Switcher
    Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dashboard-switcher/
    Description: Adds a dropdown list of the sites with every site owned in a network to quickly switch between them.
    Version: 0.1
    Author: Ezequiel Livinsky
    Author URI: http://livindev.com.ar
*/

    add_action('in_admin_header', 'own_favorite_actions');
    function own_favorite_actions() {
        if(!is_super_admin()) return;

        global $wpdb, $current_blog;

        $blogs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT domain FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE blog_id <> $current_blog->blog_id", ARRAY_A);

        $actions = array();
        foreach($blogs as $row){
            $url = 'http://'.$row['domain'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $actions[$url] = $row['domain'];
        }

        $first = array_keys($actions);
        $first = $first[0];
        echo '<div id="favorite-actions">';
        echo '<div id="favorite-first"><a href="' . $first . '">' . $actions[$first] . '</a></div><div id="favorite-toggle"><br /></div>';
        echo '<div id="favorite-inside">';
        foreach ( $actions as $action => $label) {
            echo "<div class='favorite-action'><a href='$action'>";
            echo $label;
            echo "</a></div>\n";
        }
        echo "</div></div>\n";
    }

?>
```

Comment: We can't know without knowing the full details behind `$wpdb`, `$current_blog`, and basically everything else.

Comment: @Seth: I don't know about `$current_blog`, but `$wpdb` is a Wordpress thing.

Comment: You might have more luck on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is output without any sanitization (ie. htmlspecialchars) via $action and $first so it provides an XSS (Cross site scripting) vulnerability.

For example, `/index.php?foo="><script>alert("hi!");</script><"`
would be output as `<a href="/index.php?foo="><script>alert("hi!");</script><">label</a>` which allows an attacker to give out a URL which runs javascript from your domain.

<strike>This might be mitigated in practice by magic_quotes_gpc but it's still a notable vulnerability which should be fixed.</strike>

Comment: `magic_quotes_gpc` will NOT defend against XSS. It only tries to defend against SQLi (and fails horribly at it). That's why it was removed in 5.4...